# Making one element's width dependent upon its sibling's width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a widget such that a subtitle can never be longer than a title. So the title would control the width of the widget, and the subtitle would wrap if it got wider than the title. And I'm trying to do it without JavaScript if possible.

I got close (see snippet below). I was able to make the subtitle artificially short, but even in that case, the row it's in for some reason expanded to fit the whole space of the container, instead of just the space used by its child! in fact, the space it took up is exactly what it would be if it weren't wrapped.

```css
#container {
  background: #DDD; 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

#subtitle {
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 id="title">Title that is fairly long</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h3 id="subtitle">Subtitle that is a long subtitle and that is even longer and oh it is just so super!</h3>
  </div>        
</div>
```

I need to keep subtitle in the flow (not `position:absolute`), and the title needs to be able to wrap if it gets super long (so it won't just spill off the page).
Is there any way to have two rows, one below the other, and the one can only ever be as long as the other one is?

Comment: A fixed-width container is not an option in my case -- the widget needs to have a dynamic width (based on the title).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a CSS table to me:

```css
#container {
  background: #DDD; 
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.row > * {
  display: table-cell;
}
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table-cell;
}
#title {
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 id="title">Title that is fairly long</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h3 id="subtitle">Subtitle that is a long subtitle and that is even longer and oh it is just so super!</h3>
  </div>        
</div>
```

`width:1px` on the title causes that column to collapse. `white-space:nowrap` prevents the title from wrapping. Since it's using table layout, this combination causes the width of the column to be determined by the title and so the subtitle follows along. `:after` provides us with a flexible column to fill out the table.

(Once [CSS Grid becomes available](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid), that might be preferable.)

---

You mentioned long titles. With that possibility, you'll need to switch to Javascript. (The Javascript below needs to be either somewhere after the section being affected or be run on page load.)

```js
var title = document.getElementById('title'),
    subtitle = document.getElementById('subtitle'),
    subtitleResize = function() {
      subtitle.style.width = title.clientWidth + 'px';
    };
window.addEventListener('resize', subtitleResize, false);
subtitleResize();
```

```css
#container {
  background: #DDD; 
}

#title {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 id="title">Title that is fairly long</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h3 id="subtitle">Subtitle that is a long subtitle and that is even longer and oh it is just so super!</h3>
  </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: That's cool, thanks. I should have mentioned in my question... the title needs to be able to wrap (if it got super long, it'd need to be able to wrap to two lines instead of spilling off the screen). Any ideas?

Comment: Super long? What is that? CSS can't guess what you want. It needs to know where to wrap.

Comment: If the title were as wide as the viewport, it'd need to start wrapping to two lines.

Comment: @skitterm If that's requirement, then you'll need Javascript. CSS has come a long way, but you can only get so far with these kind of shenanigans.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I can't have my cake and eat it too. Makes sense that wanting the element "out of flow" for width and "in flow" for everything else wouldn't be currently possible.

Comment: @Skitterm Added JS variant.

Answer (score -1):

You have add `white-space: nowrap;` to the h1 tag which makes the full width

[Please check the fiddle answer here](https://jsfiddle.net/en2qstgm/)